# How to use JDBC to connect a java file to MySQL on MacOS?

Tags: java, mysql, macos, sublimetext

I want to be able to create a file in a textEditor like sublimeText and from that file create a connection to MySQL, in netbeans you add the JDBC jar file to the libraries folder, i don't know how to do the same without using netbeans, i want to be able to do it on my own withtout an IDE, just with a textEditor.

P.S. I'm also on a Mac OS.

Comment: Files don't connect, *programs* do. Are you asking if you can write a Java program to connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add JDBC jar to classpath for compilation and running of your application. Like this (assuming you have `lib` directory with suitable JDBC jar in it):

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/jdbc.jar src/com/example/YourApplication.java
```

And to run

```
java -cp bin:lib/jdbc.jar com.example.YourApplication
```

You could find more information here: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: I have a folder where i stored all of my java files in:  desktop/ProyectoAlgoritmos
In ProyectoAlgoritmos i have a file called DBConnection.java and also i have  a lib folder where i placed the .jar file

Comment: So you just need to adjust commands from above according to your directories structure. That's it